# Unable to connect to mysql db via robotframework

Tags: robotframework, mysql-python

I am trying to connect MySQL DB in robot framework. But I am receiving the following error:

> Operational Error: (1045, u"Access denied for user
>   'ABC'@'Nd204-151-102-92.com' (using password: YES)")

I have used the Database Library and the following code :

```
      *** Settings ***
  Library           Database Library
  Library           pymysql

     *** Variable ***
  ${DBHost}           value4
  ${DBName}           value1
  ${DBPass}          "value2"
  ${DBPort}           port
  ${DBUser}          value3


    *** Keywords ***
Connect to DB 
Connect To Database    pymysql  ${DbName}    ${DBUser}    ${DBPass}    
${DBHost}    ${DBPort} 
${output}=    Query    select * from tables;
```

Comment: The error comes from your DB and it literally says the access is denied for that user/password combo. What is your question?

Comment: Can you please show how you are defining the username and password?

Comment: Its mentioned in error message that user ABC is not having access either due to the wrong password or not having access to read the specified database.

Comment: @YashJagdale: yes, but the error message looks rather curious. There are quote marks around the username and the hostname, and I'm wondering if the OP has those quotes in their actual data.

Comment: It may be because an error is a dictionary object, And its string containing string. Its thought never tried.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley I am defining the username and password and in my variables section in  the same robot file : like      under *** Variables ***    ${DBUser}  = 'DBuser'  and ${DBPass}  =  'dbpassword'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're setting the values.

Comment: also @YashJagdale I am able to connect with the same username and password via mysql toad , dont know whats going wrong with robot

Comment: Ohh @rishumalani dont add ‘ while setting up both username and password. Keep them as plain text.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @YashJagdale that worked :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're adding quote marks around your username and password. The error message seems to imply this, and you added the following in a comment:

> I am defining the username and password and in my variables section in the same robot file : like under`*** Variables *** ${DBUser} = 'DBuser' and ${DBPass} = 'dbpassword'`

Assuming the username is the six character string `DBuser` and the password is the 10 character string `dbpassword`, you need to define it like this:

```
*** Variables ***
${DBUser}    DBuser
${DBPASS|    dbpassword
```

Notice the lack of an `=`, and there are no quotes.

Comment: Hi Bryan thanks for the constant help , it worked . :)  I am able to fetch details from DB .